# Android Data Binding: Wrong BR class generated for obfuscated AAR

Tags: android, data-binding, proguard, aar

I'd like to provide an obfuscated AAR library which makes use of Android data binding. When I use the library from a test app, everything works fine as long as the library isn't minified by ProGuard. However, after enabling ProGuard the test app doesn't compile any more since BR fields in the generated data binding classes can't be found.

Since I couldn't find any official documentation on this "specific" subject, I tried to understand the magic behind Android data binding. The mechanism seem to be like this (please correct me, if I'm wrong):

- In order to use data binding within an AAR lib, the embedding app must enable data binding, too.
- This is because the the layout resources that contain data binding instructions are included without modification in the AAR.
- It's therefore the embedding app's responsibility to generate the corresponding data binding classes for the layouts in the lib. (That's why the lib's view model classes must not be obfuscated, BTW.)
- The challenge for the Android data binding generator is to tell the package names apart from both library and embedding app: The BR class for the library must be generated in the library's package (e. g. com.example.lib.databinding), since this class is accessed from the library's view model classes. On the other hand, the BR class of the embedding app should normally be generated within the app's package (com.example.app.databinding).

And this is exactly where my problems begin. I don't know Android exactly rises to this challenge, I only know that in my case, it works with an unobfuscated lib, and it doesn't with an obfuscated one. When I look into the generated source of the embedding app, I see:

- When using the unobfuscated lib, both the BR and all *Binding.java classes are generated within the library's package, and the app compiles.
- When using the obfuscated lib, both the BR and all *Binding.java classes are generated within the apps's package. Even worse, the BR only contains constants for the model variable names in the XML resource, not for the properties in the view model classes. Consequently, the app doesn't compile.
- I tried to set the package of the data binding classes explicitely to the lib's package in the XML  declaration, but this doesn't solve the problem with the incomplete BR class.

I have no clue where these differences come from and I' already fearing that the only solution could be removing all my nice data binding stuff from the lib ... Does anybody made similar experiences and could give me a hint, please?

These are the ProGuard exceptions I've already added to my lib:

```
-keep public class **.BR { public *; }
-keep public class **.BR$* { public *; }
-keepclassmembers class **.BR$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
-keep class android.databinding.** { *; }
-keep class * extends android.databinding.** { *; }
-keep class com.example.lib.databinding.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Google has resolved the issue with Gradle plugin 2.3.0, see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229684.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it run in the meantime, but the "solution" is so weird that I really don't want to take it over to a productive version ...

When comparing the AAR files of the obfuscated and unobfuscated lib, I noticed that the classes.jar of the unobfuscated one contained these three files:

- /com/example/lib/com.example.lib-br.bin
- /com/example/lib/com.example.lib-layoutinfo.bin
- /com/example/lib/com.example.lib-setter_store.bin

These binary files contain some of my data binding class names and are apparently important for the code generation process. I just tried to copy these files into the corresponding place of my obfuscated AAR and ... it worked!!!

But this cannot be the final solution. At least it would be more reliable than coping if I can convince ProGuard to simply keep these non-class-files within the classes.jar. Any ideas how to do this?

Much more I would appreciate to get some information on the backgrounds of this mechanism and whether it is possible to avoid such ugly low-level operations for solving a problem that actually should be standard.

Thanks in advance for any answer!

Comment: I've filed a bug at the Android team about this:

Comment: Is there a Gradle task that can do this...this is super annoying :-(